# Solving for a lower bound in intergration

Tags: integration

I was given the following problem.

Find $m$ such that:

$$\int_{m}^{-2}\frac{1}{4-x}\mathrm{d}x=\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

I just started intergration so I know the basics. However, I do no recall learning this part and I am stuck. What I was thinking was to find the $F(b)$ and then subtract that from the area. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int\frac{dx}{4-x}=\ln|4-x|$$

Now we want that

$$\int_{m}^{-2}\frac{dx}{4-x}=\ln|3/2|$$

So

$$\ln|4-m|-\ln|4-(-2)|=\ln|3/2|$$

$$\ln|\frac{4-m}{6}|=\ln|3/2|$$

$$4-m=9\\
m=-5$$

Comment: yep, the answer is -5 i think

Answer (score 0):

you have $$\int_m^{-2} \frac{dx}{4-x} = \ln\left(\frac{4-m}{6}\right) = \ln\left(\frac 3 2\right) \implies m = -5.$$